# how to Detect packers and beautifies this js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hex, decode, packer

How Detect packers and beautifies this JS below? I've tried hexdecoder tool like : http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder and http://jsbeautifier.org etc.
But after decode js not working and not properly decode.

**JS:**

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('4f 3B=["(3($){\'31 38\';X.1g=X.1g||3(){m+R X()};$.p=3(g){4 h=$.37({},$.p.22,g);4 i=R $.p.1u();4 j=R $.p.1M(h.F);4 k=(h.x?R $.p.x():v);4 l=8;3 A(){4 d;j.2p(3(a,b,c){6(k){k.20(a,c)}h.21.y(8,a,c,b)});V();6(k&&k.1B()){D();d=k.1O();i.1p(3(){4 a;6(d>1){1w(d);a=1d(G);$(\'N, 1c\').Q(a)}w{V()}})}m l}A();3 V(){1G();h.F.1j(S)}3 S(){4 a,1o;a=i.T(h.F);1o=1d();6(a>=1o){6(29()>=h.2a){D();2k(3(){1b(a)})}w{1b(a)}}}3 D(){h.F.36(\'1j\',S)}3 1G(){$(h.1i).11()}3 1d(a){4 b,18;b=$(h.q).I(h.C).P();6(b.1J()===0){m 0}18=b.2g().2j+b.17();6(!a){18+=h.2n}m 18}3 1b(d,e){4 f;f=$(h.1k).1N(\'U\');6(!f){6(h.1P){$(h.q).I(h.C).P().15(h.1P)}m D()}6(h.14&&$.35(h.14)){6(h.14(d,f)===v){m}}j.1T(d,f);D();1U();1X(f,3(a,b){4 c=h.1Z.y(8,b),1q;6(c!==v){$(b).11();1q=$(h.q).I(h.C).P();1q.15(b);$(b).1s()}f=$(h.1k,a).1N(\'U\');$(h.1i).34($(h.1i,a));23();1G();6(f){V()}w{D()}h.26.y(8,b);6(e){e.y(8)}})}3 1X(b,c,d){4 e=[],q,27=X.1g(),13,12;d=d||h.2b;$.2c(b,2e,3(a){q=$(h.q,a).2f(0);6(0===q.B){q=$(a).33(h.q).2f(0)}6(q){q.I(h.C).32(3(){e.1A(8)})}6(c){12=8;13=X.1g()-27;6(13<d){2m(3(){c.y(12,a,e)},d-13)}w{c.y(12,a,e)}}},\'N\')}3 1w(a){4 b=1d(G);6(b>0){1b(b,3(){D();6((j.M(b)+1)<a){1w(a);$(\'N,1c\').1R({\'Q\':b},30,\'1K\')}w{$(\'N,1c\').1R({\'Q\':b},1L,\'1K\');V()}})}}3 29(){4 a=i.T(h.F);m j.M(a)}3 1F(){4 a=$(\'.19\');6(a.1J()===0){a=$(\'<L K=\\"19\\">\'+h.19+\'</L>\');a.11()}m a}3 1U(){4 a=1F(),J;6(h.1m!==v){h.1m(a)}w{J=$(h.q).I(h.C).P();J.15(a);a.1s()}}3 23(){4 a=1F();a.1Q()}3 1n(a){4 b=$(\'.16\');6(b.1J()===0){b=$(\'<L K=\\"16\\"><a U=\\"\\">\'+h.16+\'2Y 2W</a></L>\');b.11()}$(\'a\',b).2V(\'1W\').2Q(\'1W\',3(){1Y();a.y();m v});m b}3 2k(a){4 b=1n(a),J;J=$(h.q).I(h.C).P();J.15(b);b.1s()}3 1Y(){4 a=1n();a.1Q()}};$.p.22={q:\'.1r-2O\',F:$(z),C:\'.2N-2M\',1i:\'#1r-24\',1k:\'#1r-24-2J-2H a\',19:\'<i K=\\"H H-2G H-2E H-2D\\"></i>\',2b:1L,2a:2,16:\'<i K=\\"H H-2C\\"></i>\',2n:-2B,x:G,21:3(){},14:3(){},1Z:3(){},26:3(){2A.2z.2y();2x.2w.2v();2u.2t.2l();2s.1A([\'2r\'])},1m:v};$.p.1u=3(){4 c=v;4 d=v;4 e=8;3 A(){$(z).2l(3(){c=G})}A();8.1p=3(a){$(\'N,1c\').Q(0);6(!d){6(!c){2m(3(){e.1p(a)},1)}w{a.y();d=G}}};8.T=3(a){4 b,1I;6(a.2c(0)===z){b=a.Q()}w{b=a.2g().2j}1I=a.17();m b+1I}};$.p.1M=3(){4 c=[[0,1l.1H.2P()]];4 d=3(){};4 e=1;4 f=R $.p.1u();3 A(){$(z).1j(S)}A();3 S(){4 a,O,1h,1E,1D;a=f.T($(z));O=M(a);1h=2h(a);6(e!==O){1E=1h[0];1D=1h[1];d.y({},O,1E,1D)}e=O}3 M(a){1C(4 i=(c.B-1);i>0;i--){6(a>c[i][0]){m i+1}}m 1}8.M=3(a){a=a||f.T($(z));m M(a)};3 2h(a){1C(4 i=(c.B-1);i>=0;i--){6(a>c[i][0]){m c[i]}}m 2e}8.2p=3(a){d=a};8.1T=3(a,b){c.1A([a,b])}};$.p.x=3(){4 e=v;4 f=v;3 A(){f=!!(z.x&&x.Y&&x.1f);f=v}A();8.20=3(a,b){8.2d({W:a},\'\',b)};8.1B=3(){m(8.1z()!==v)};8.1O=3(){4 a;6(8.1B()){a=8.1z();m a.W}m 1};8.1z=3(){4 a,Z,1x;6(f){Z=x.2F;6(Z&&Z.p){m Z.p}}w{a=(z.1H.28.1v(0,7)===\'/\');6(a){1x=2I(z.1H.28.25(\'/\',\'\'),10);m{W:1x}}}m v};8.2d=3(a,b,c){6(e){8.1f(a,b,c)}w{8.Y(a,b,c)}};8.Y=3(a,b,c){4 d;6(f){x.Y({p:a},b,c)}w{d=(a.W>0?\'/\'+a.W:\'\')}e=G};8.1f=3(a,b,c){6(f){x.1f({p:a},b,c)}w{8.Y(a,b,c)}}}})(2K);3 2L(e,t){6(e.1a(\\"<\\")!=-1){4 n=e.2q(\\"<\\");1C(4 r=0;r<n.B;r++){6(n[r].1a(\\">\\")!=-1){n[r]=n[r].1v(n[r].1a(\\">\\")+1,n[r].B)}}e=n.2R(\\"\\")}t=t<e.B-1?t:e.B-2;2S(e.2T(t-1)!=\\" \\"&&e.1a(\\" \\",t)!=-1)t++;e=e.1v(0,t-1);m e+\\"\\"}3 2U(e,t,n){4 r=1l.1V(e);4 i=1l.1V(n);4 s=/\\\\/s([2X]?[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2Z)[^0-9]/;4 o=\'<a U=\\"\'+t+\'\\" 2o=\\"\\"><1y 2i=\\"\\" 1t=\\"#\\" 1S=\\"\'+E+\'1e\\" 17=\\"\'+E+\'1e\\"/></a>\';4 u=r.39(\\"1y\\");6(u.B>=1){o=\'<a K=\\"3a\\" U=\\"\'+t+\'\\" 3b-2o=\\"\'+n+\'\\"><1y 2i=\\"\'+n+\'\\" 1t=\\"\'+u[0].1t.25(s,\\"/s\\"+E+\\"-c/\\")+\'\\" 1S=\\"\'+E+\'1e\\" 17=\\"\'+E+\'1e\\"/><L K=\\"3c\\"></L></a>\'}4 a=o;r.3d=a}4 E=3e","\\3f","\\3o\\3u\\3l\\3n\\3h","\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3w\\3t\\3p\\3s\\3h\\3n\\3k\\3p\\3f\\3G\\3i\\3j\\3f\\3f\\3n\\3w\\3f\\3f\\3h\\3q\\3n\\3o\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3h\\3t\\3j\\3p\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3n\\3i\\3o\\3f\\3s\\3k\\3p\\3h\\3i\\3n\\3p\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3f\\3w\\3i\\3l\\3o\\3g\\3f\\3g\\3l\\3o\\3g\\3f\\3q\\3n\\3o\\3h\\3k\\3j\\3I\\3f\\3s\\3i\\3l\\3l\\3f\\3z\\3n\\3p\\3r\\3k\\3z\\3f\\3n\\3p\\3n\\3h\\3f\\3l\\3g\\3p\\3m\\3h\\3q\\3f\\3n\\3h\\3g\\3v\\3f\\3o\\3h\\3k\\3u\\3A\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3f\\3n\\3z\\3q\\3f\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3E\\3k\\3p\\3h\\3i\\3n\\3p\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3h\\3j\\3t\\3g\\3f\\3w\\3i\\3f\\3w\\3n\\3p\\3r\\3f\\3g\\3l\\3f\\3s\\3l\\3i\\3o\\3o\\3f\\3r\\3n\\3G\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3E\\3t\\3j\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3P\\3t\\3v\\3f\\3q\\3h\\3v\\3l\\3f\\3s\\3t\\3j\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3P\\3t\\3v\\3f\\3l\\3i\\3o\\3h\\3f\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3C\\3k\\3u\\3f\\3p\\3g\\3z\\3f\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3A\\3q\\3i\\3p\\3r\\3l\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3E\\3t\\3j\\3j\\3g\\3p\\3h\\3J\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3Q\\3w\\3w\\3o\\3g\\3h\\3f\\3q\\3j\\3g\\3w\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3o\\3g\\3h\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\43\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3u\\3t\\3o\\3q\\3J\\3h\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3o\\3h\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3Q\\3F\\3X\\3f\\3f\\3q\\3n\\3r\\3g\\3f\\3o\\3g\\3l\\3w\\3f\\3r\\3n\\3w\\3w\\3C\\3n\\3v\\3g\\3f\\3F\\3g\\3w\\3k\\3j\\3g\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3E\\3q\\3i\\3p\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3i\\3w\\3h\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3m\\3m\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3q\\3g\\3n\\3m\\3q\\3h\\3f\\3h\\3q\\3j\\3g\\3o\\3q\\3k\\3l\\3r\\3f\\3l\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3n\\3p\\3r\\3g\\3N\\3Q\\3w\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3n\\3p\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3F\\3k\\3r\\3I\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3A\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3A\\3h\\3q\\3j\\3g\\3o\\3q\\3k\\3l\\3r\\3f\\3u\\3N\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3u\\3l\\3i\\3s\\3g\\3J\\3h\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3p\\3k\\3z\\3f\\3s\\3t\\3j\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3F\\3j\\3g\\3i\\3O\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3n\\3p\\3i\\3h\\3n\\3k\\3p\\3f\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3f\\3p\\3g\\3N\\3h\\3f\\3r\\3k\\3s\\3t\\3v\\3g\\3p\\3h\\3f\\3s\\3t\\3o\\3h\\3k\\3v\\3K\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3g\\3j\\3y\\3j\\3k\\3s\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3A\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3m\\3m\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3C\\3q\\3j\\3g\\3o\\3q\\3k\\3l\\3r\\3f\\3w\\3k\\3j\\3s\\3g\\3J\\3s\\3j\\3k\\3l\\3l\\3C\\3k\\3u\\3f\\3s\\3t\\3j\\3K\\3i\\3o\\3h\\3L\\3h\\3g\\3v\\3f\\3F\\3l\\3k\\3m\\3f\\3w\\3i\\3r\\3g\\3L\\3p\\3f\\3o\\3j\\3s\\3f\\3t\\3h\\3n\\3l\\3f\\3o\\3t\\3F\\3o\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3p\\3m\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3n\\3p\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3C\\3k\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3P\\3t\\3v\\3f\\3n\\3v\\3m\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3J\\3h\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3u\\3t\\3o\\3q\\3f\\3q\\3i\\3G\\3g\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3w\\3k\\3j\\3f\\3t\\3j\\3l\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3o\\3s\\3j\\3Q\\3w\\3w\\3o\\3g\\3h\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3A\\3l\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3q\\3n\\3r\\3g\\3A\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3n\\3p\\3i\\3h\\3n\\3k\\3p\\3f\\3l\\3k\\3s\\3i\\3h\\3n\\3k\\3p\\3f\\3z\\3p\\3r\\3Y\\3g\\3n\\3m\\3q\\3h\\3f\\3o\\3n\\4b\\3g\\3f\\3o\\3z\\3n\\3p\\3m\\3f\\3Z\\3D\\3D\\3D\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3n\\3p\\3m\\3f\\3i\\3h\\3h\\3j\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3p\\3k\\3p\\3g\\3l\\3g\\3w\\3h\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3v\\3k\\3G\\3g\\3f\\3i\\3p\\3n\\3v\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3z\\3n\\3r\\3h\\3q\\3f\\3u\\3t\\3o\\3q\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3o\\3f\\3o\\3q\\3k\\3z\\3A\\3l\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\44\\3l\\3g\\3v\\3g\\3p\\3h\\3R\\3I\\3L\\3r\\3f\\3s\\3l\\3n\\3s\\3O\\3f\\3l\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3L\\3h\\3g\\3v\\3o\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3v\\3k\\3G\\3g\\3A\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3m\\3m\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3k\\3p\\3K\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3L\\3h\\3g\\3v\\3o\\3f\\3o\\3g\\3h\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3k\\3p\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3E\\3q\\3i\\3p\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3r\\3g\\3w\\3i\\3t\\3l\\3h\\3o\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3v\\3k\\3G\\3g\\3A\\3l\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3u\\3l\\3i\\3s\\3g\\3f\\3k\\3p\\4c\\3g\\3p\\3r\\3g\\3j\\3E\\3k\\3v\\3u\\3l\\3g\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3o\\3h\\3i\\3j\\3h\\3C\\3n\\3v\\3g\\3f\\3q\\3i\\3o\\3q\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3A\\3s\\3t\\3j\\3j\\3g\\3p\\3h\\3A\\3u\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3m\\3m\\3g\\3j\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3C\\3q\\3j\\3g\\3o\\3q\\3k\\3l\\3r\\3f\\3l\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3g\\3j\\43\\3g\\3l\\3i\\3I\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3f\\3t\\3u\\3r\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3J\\3h\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3p\\3t\\3l\\3l\\3f\\3g\\45\\3f\\3k\\3w\\3w\\3o\\3g\\3h\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3E\\3t\\3j\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3F\\3j\\3g\\3i\\3O\\3f\\3i\\3l\\3h\\3f\\3h\\3k\\3u\\3f\\3o\\3q\\3k\\3z\\3A\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3m\\3m\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3l\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3f\\3o\\3g\\3h\\3C\\3n\\3v\\3g\\3k\\3t\\3h\\3f\\3h\\3q\\3j\\3g\\3o\\3q\\3k\\3l\\3r\\3S\\3i\\3j\\3m\\3n\\3p\\3f\\3h\\3n\\3h\\3l\\3g\\3f\\3k\\3p\\3E\\3q\\3i\\3p\\3m\\3g\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3f\\3o\\3u\\3l\\3n\\3h\\3f\\3A\\3h\\3j\\3i\\3s\\3O\\3y\\3i\\3m\\3g\\3G\\3n\\3g\\3z\\3f\\3A\\3m\\3i\\45\\3f\\3z\\3n\\3r\\3m\\3g\\3h\\3o\\3f\\3h\\3z\\3h\\3h\\3j\\3f\\3m\\3k\\3f\\3u\\3l\\3t\\3o\\3k\\3p\\3g\\3f\\3m\\3i\\3u\\3n\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3j\\3o\\3g\\3f\\4d\\40\\3R\\3S\\3K\\3f\\40\\3R\\3f\\4e\\3D\\3D\\3f\\3u\\3l\\3t\\3o\\3f\\3o\\3u\\3n\\3p\\3f\\46\\3N\\3f\\3o\\3h\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3s\\3k\\3m\\3f\\3l\\3n\\3p\\3O\\3f\\3u\\3i\\3j\\3o\\3g\\3L\\3p\\3h\\3f\\3k\\3l\\3r\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3X\\4g\\3t\\3g\\3j\\3I\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3v\\3k\\3G\\3g\\3Y\\3h\\3v\\3l\\3C\\3i\\3m\\3f\\3k\\3t\\3h\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3r\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3f\\3u\\3k\\3o\\3h\\3o\\3f\\3h\\3k\\3J\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3p\\3m\\3f\\3k\\3p\\3f\\3X\\3k\\3n\\3p\\3f\\3z\\3q\\3n\\3l\\3g\\3f\\3s\\3q\\3i\\3j\\47\\3h\\3f\\3s\\3j\\3g\\3i\\3h\\3g\\3J\\3t\\3v\\3v\\3i\\3j\\3I\\47\\3p\\3r\\3C\\3q\\3t\\3v\\3F\\3f\\3k\\3w\\3w\\3f\\3S\\3k\\3j\\3g\\3f\\3D\\3Z\\3f\\3K\\3k\\3i\\3r\\3f\\3Z\\4h\\3D\\3D\\3f\\46\\3D\\3D\\3f\\3t\\3o\\3g\\3f\\3g\\3i\\3s\\3q\\3f\\3w\\3n\\3l\\3h\\3g\\3j\\3f\\3j\\3g\\3u\\3l\\3i\\3s\\3g\\4i\\3n\\3h\\3q\\3f\\3n\\3o\\40\\3t\\3p\\3s\\3h\\3n\\3k\\3p\\3f\\3t\\3p\\3F\\3n\\3p\\3r\\3f\\3g\\3N\\3h\\3g\\3p\\3r\\3f\\3o\\3h\\3j\\3n\\3s\\3h\\3f\\3m\\3g\\3h\\44\\3l\\3g\\3v\\3g\\3p\\3h\\3o\\3R\\3I\\3C\\3i\\3m\\3P\\3i\\3v\\3g\\3f\\3h\\3k\\3u\\3h\\3n\\3u\\3f\\3r\\3i\\3h\\3i\\3f\\3k\\3G\\3g\\3j\\3l\\3i\\3I\\3f\\3n\\3p\\3p\\3g\\3j\\3Y\\3C\\3S\\3K\\3f\\4j\\4k\\3D","","\\3w\\3j\\3k\\3v\\3E\\3q\\3i\\3j\\3E\\3k\\3r\\3g","\\3j\\3g\\3u\\3l\\3i\\3s\\3g","\\48\\3z\\4l","\\48\\3F","\\3m"];4m(3T(3U,3V,3x,3M,3H,41){3H=3T(3x){3W(3x<3V?3B[4]:3H(4n(3x/3V)))+((3x=3x%3V)>35?49[3B[5]](3x+29):3x.4o(36))};4a(!3B[4][3B[6]](/^/,49)){42(3x--){41[3H(3x)]=3M[3x]||3H(3x)};3M=[3T(3H){3W 41[3H]}];3H=3T(){3W 3B[7]};3x=1};42(3x--){4a(3M[3x]){3U=3U[3B[6]](4p 4q(3B[8]+3H(3x)+3B[8],3B[9]),3M[3x])}};3W 3U}(3B[0],4r,4s,3B[3][3B[2]](3B[1]),0,{}))',62,277,'|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||x7C|x65|x74|x61|x72|x6F|x6C|x67|x69|x73|x6E|x68|x64|x63|x75|x70|x6D|x66|_0x936bx3|x50|x77|x5F|_0x9d83|x54|x30|x43|x62|x76|_0x936bx5|x79|x53|x4C|x49|_0x936bx4|x78|x6B|x4E|x4F|x42|x4D|function|_0x936bx1|_0x936bx2|return|x6A|x48|x31|x46|_0x936bx6|while|x44|x45|x71|x34|x41|x5C|String|if|x7A|x52|x58|x35|var|x51|x36|x57|x32|x37|x2B|eval|parseInt|toString|new|RegExp|62|201'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Please help, is there any solution?

Comment: You might be able to get it to tab/indent properly using a prettifier, but without a sourcemap to the source code you're not going to be able to re-inflate any of the minified var or function names...

Comment: ok, but after prettify, js not works.

Comment: @anied: Neither decoder produces valid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those beautifiers try to unpack common packers. Either they're out of date, or someone wrote a new packer that uses the same format as an existing one, which tricks them.

You can unpack it (and many other packers) by patching `eval` and having it print things out:

```
var old_eval = window.eval;

window.eval = function(code) {
    console.log('Running', code);

    return old_eval(code);
};
```

When you execute your code, it'll unpack itself normally but also print the code out to your console.

Comment: @Aariba: Open up your browser's JavaScript console, run my code to patch `window.eval`, then run your code. You can then see the unpacked code get printed out.

Comment: hi, thanks again, done it, it unpacked, but getting error `VM902:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:6175)
    at window.eval (<anonymous>:6:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:9451)
    at window.eval (<anonymous>:6:12)
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: @Aariba: I don't know if it'll work in IE's developer tools, try Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Chrome Process:  Fast i run your code on browser Console, after execute your code, i place my code below next line, then run my code. Then it unpacked, but getting `Uncaught ReferenceError`

Comment: @Aariba: My code helps you see what's being executed, that's all. Look through the console's output and you'll see the original source code.

Comment: Thanks, please do you provide me the executed unpacked `code` here?